# Uploaded black images to Azure Blob

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure-blob-storage

We have an application where we use the Azure Blob Storage service to save our files. Some months ago, the images were stored correctly.

However, nowadays we upload the images but they aren't saved. There are saved black images.

We have developed the application with angular.

**Edit (added the following):**

Here is the code:

```
module.exports.addImage = (userId, data) ->
  p = new hope.Promise
  headers =
    contentType: 'image/jpg'
    contentEncoding: 'base64'

  imageUid = uid 64
  imageName = imageUid + '.jpg'
  image = new Buffer data, 'base64'

  jimp.read image, (error, img) ->
    if error
      return p.done error
    img.resize(200, 200).getBuffer jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, result) ->
      return p.done error if error
      blobService = azure.createBlobService AZURE_BLOB, AZURE_BLOB_SECRET

      blobService.createBlockBlobFromText 'profile', imageName,
        result, headers, (error, result, response) ->
          return p.done error if error

          Profile.findOne {user: new objectId(userId)}, (error, profile) ->
            return p.done error if error
            if !profile
              return p.done null, null
            profile.profileImage = imageName
            profile.save (error) ->
              if error
                return p.done error
              return p.done null, true

  return p
```

**Edit 2 (added the angularjs code, it is in coffescript)**

```
article#profile__edit--photo
            h3 {{'PROFILE_PHOTO' | translate}}
            div
              label(for='profile-image')
                | {{'PROFILE_IMAGE' | translate}}
                span.form-group-help Opcional
              input#image.form-control(type='file', accept='image/*', onchange='angular.element(this).scope().handleFileSelect(this)')
            .cropArea
              img-crop(image='image.profileImage', result-image='image.croppedImage')
```

Jimp version: 0.2.27

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Yes, of course. I edited the post.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this at the moment. It seems to be an issue with jimp. BTW, which [version of jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/releases) are you using and can you also post your angularjs code here?